# Spring Boot + Hibernate Search: Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, hibernate-search, sessionfactory

I am working on a Spring Boot project with JPA and want to use the Hibernate Search (API) to search for full-text queries. There are no errors when I compile the code, but when I add annotations to my entityclass to enable full-text search capabilities and run the code, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at com.jdh.pilih2.Pilih2Application.main(Pilih2Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:382) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:371) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336) ~[spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000103: Unable to initialize IndexManager named 'com.jdh.pilih2.domain.Product'
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerGroupHolder.doCreateIndexManager(IndexManagerGroupHolder.java:198) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.9.0.Final.jar:5.9.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerGroupHolder.getOrCreateIndexManager(IndexManagerGroupHolder.java:155) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.9.0.Final.jar:5.9.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.NotShardedEntityIndexBinder.bind(NotShardedEntityIndexBinder.java:34) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.9.0.Final.jar:5.9.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerGroupHolder.bind(IndexManagerGroupHolder.java:100) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.9.0.Final.jar:5.9.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.buildEntityIndexBinding(IndexManagerHolder.java:100) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.9.0.Final.jar:5.9.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.initDocumentBuilders(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:428) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.9.0.Final.jar:5.9.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.createNewFactoryState(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:244) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.9.0.Final.jar:5.9.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.buildNewSearchFactory(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:200) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.9.0.Final.jar:5.9.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.buildSearchIntegrator(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:128) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.9.0.Final.jar:5.9.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.boot(HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.java:113) ~[hibernate-search-orm-5.9.0.Final.jar:5.9.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.sessionFactoryCreated(HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.java:79) ~[hibernate-search-orm-5.9.0.Final.jar:5.9.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:532) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000252: Unable to initialize directory provider org.hibernate.search.store.impl.FSDirectoryProvider for index com.jdh.pilih2.domain.Product
    at org.hibernate.search.store.spi.BaseDirectoryProviderService.initialize(BaseDirectoryProviderService.java:79) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.9.0.Final.jar:5.9.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.store.spi.BaseDirectoryProviderService.create(BaseDirectoryProviderService.java:64) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.9.0.Final.jar:5.9.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.spi.DirectoryBasedIndexManager.createDirectoryProvider(DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java:229) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.9.0.Final.jar:5.9.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.spi.DirectoryBasedIndexManager.initialize(DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java:89) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.9.0.Final.jar:5.9.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerGroupHolder.doCreateIndexManager(IndexManagerGroupHolder.java:195) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.9.0.Final.jar:5.9.0.Final]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: Unable to create index directory: /data/index/default for index com.jdh.pilih2.domain.Product
    at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.DirectoryProviderHelper.makeSanityCheckedDirectory(DirectoryProviderHelper.java:145) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.9.0.Final.jar:5.9.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.store.spi.DirectoryHelper.getVerifiedIndexPath(DirectoryHelper.java:89) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.9.0.Final.jar:5.9.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.FSDirectoryProvider.initialize(FSDirectoryProvider.java:50) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.9.0.Final.jar:5.9.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.store.spi.BaseDirectoryProviderService.initialize(BaseDirectoryProviderService.java:76) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.9.0.Final.jar:5.9.0.Final]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
```

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.package</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-name</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>project-name</name>
    <description>Project Description</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And this is my POJO with JPA / Hibernate annotations:

```
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name="products")
@Indexed
public class Product implements Serializable{

    /** int value that represents the id of the product */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    /** String value that represents the brandname */
    @Field
    private String brand;

    /** String value that represents the model */
    @Field
    private String model;

    /** String value that represents the sku */
    @Field
    private String sku;

    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(String brand, String model, String sku) {
        this.brand = brand;
        this.model = model;
        this.sku = sku;
    }

    /** GETTERS AND SETTERS */

}
```

I also added these two lines in my application.properties file:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.directory_provider = filesystem 
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.indexBase = /data/index/default
```

Can somebody help me with this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interesting error is this one:
Unable to create index directory: /data/index/default for index com.jdh.pilih2.domain.Product

Your Java application needs to have the permission to create new directories in /data/index/default (or even create this directory if it's missing).

I suspect it's not the case and thus Hibernate Search cannot be initialized properly.

Comment: That solved the problem, thanks! You can either set the permissions of that folder or just put it e.g. in your workfolder.